# How to use UseButton in android

Tags: android

i need UseButton in my app to link uber app.For this i have implemented the following code.In useButton Developer site, it has been said to submit for review. while filling the review form, its asking screenshot with a working button. but my button in the screen is not visible. how can it be working button.

please help me.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
RelativeLayout rootLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);

    final ButtonDropin buttonDropin = new ButtonDropin(MainActivity2.this);
    buttonDropin.setButtonId("btn-11cd09c63aaa7c02");

    buttonDropin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_app_button);
    buttonDropin.setTextSize_Button(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_text_size));
    ButtonContext contexts = null;
    try {
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        buttonDropin.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        rootLayout.addView(buttonDropin);

      contexts = ButtonContext.withSubjectLocation(new Location("Button HQ", 11.9362587, 79.8268325));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        final android.location.Location userLocations = new LocationProvider(this).getBestLocation();

        if (userLocations != null) {
            contexts.setUserLocation(new Location(userLocations));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Exception :"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

   buttonDropin.prepareForDisplay(contexts, new ButtonDropin.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final boolean isReady) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"IsReady:"+isReady,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(ButtonDropin buttonDropin) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"buttonDropin onclick",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons that need to be reviewed will still render. Also, Buttons will only render if there is inventory to display (for this example, will there be Ubers to take from where the user is to where the user is going, which set in the Context).

First, add the Button SDK to your app's build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.usebutton:android-sdk:5+'
```

Then, add Button to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application

    <activity
      <!-- your activities  -->
    </activity>

    <!--Button SDK-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.usebutton.applicationid" android:value="YOUR_BUTTON_APP_ID"/>
</application>
```

Then, import the SDK at the top of the Activity and start it. This should be called when your application class is created.

```
import com.usebutton.sdk.Button;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      Button.getButton(this).start();
  }
}
```

Then, add the Button to your view:

```
<com.usebutton.sdk.ButtonDropin
        android:id="@+id/main_dropin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

And then load the action for your Button in your Activity file:

```
final ButtonDropin buttonDropin = (ButtonDropin) findViewById(R.id.main_dropin);

// Set location to go to
final Location location = new Location("LOCATION_NAME", LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);
// Create Button Context
final ButtonContext buttonContext = ButtonContext.withSubjectLocation(location);

// Get Button Action and display if there is inventory
Button.getButton(this).getAction("YOUR_BUTTON_ID", buttonContext, "my-pub-ref", new Button.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAction(final AppAction action) {
        // Display Button
        buttonDropin.prepareWithAction(action);
    }

   @Override
    public void onNoAction() {
        // Don't display Button
        buttonDropin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```